# Adding link screws up formatting

Tags: formatting, hyperlink, hidden

I'm currently trying to add hidden links to my food festival website so that visitors can click through to the bands playing the festival. Here's the relevant page:

http://aksarbenribfest.com/#!/page_music

I added a link through Dreamweaver 5.5 to the band in the bottom of the middle column, but it screwed up my formatting and gave it that awful purple 'clicked on' color.

Any suggestions as to how to hide the link and maintain the original formatting of the other bands?

Robert Conner 
aksarbenribfest.com 
Omaha, nebraska

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your page's source, you need to do this.

http://screencast.com/t/Dqf9lXPLO

Comment: The suggested fix will COMPLETELY remove the line, not just keep it the same as the other lines.  I need keep all lines looking the same while ALSO adding an embedded link while NOT changing the appearance of the lines.  THANKS